# jQuery Rebinding a hover event (helper)

Tags: jquery, binding

When the page is done loading I call a function which puts the hover event on $('a.tooltip'). When I want to *unbind* this event I do the following:

```
   $('a.tooltip').unbind('mouseover mouseout');
```

That works! However when I want rebind the hover event and I call the function that was first loaded at document ready again, it doesn't rebind the hover helper. How can I rebind it?

Thank you,

Ice

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the unbinding is working correctly? In my experience, .hover() does rebind properly, but I have had to use this unbind syntax:

```
$(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
```

When I tried putting both events into one unbind(), it only unbound one of them.

I wonder if that's happening for you? (Or if the choice of `mouseover` vs `mouseenter`, etc, matters?)

#### Update

According to [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html), `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are IE-specific events, but as Jimmy pointed out in the comments, jQuery implements them for other browsers as well.

Comment: Thank you!! It definitly matters because this just fixed it. I am now able to .hover() again and rebinds it.

Comment: I believe jquery implements mouseenter and mouseleave

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I use the bind method, things can be a bit fussy.  You might want to try using the hover(over, out) function as such:

```
 $(this).hover( 
    function() {
       if (okayToHover) { dowhatever; } 
    },
    function() {
       if (okayToUnhover) { undowhatever; }
    });
```

I know it seems a bit roundabout, but I find that the hover function gives me a bit more control over what's going on, and it seems to work a bit better for whatever reason.  That's just in my experience though...

Comment: Behind the scenes, jQuery's .hover() is just binding traditional JS mouse events. If for some reason you wanted to disable and later re-enable hover functionality, how would you do it?